# SQL - Column Default Value computed from another table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am trying to set the Default value for a column such as (`Stores(Name)` to the value of a column in a related table (`Company(Name)`.

Definition of those two tables here:

```
CREATE TABLE Companies (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE Stores (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE Companies(Id),
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT [[unsure what to put here]] )
```

I'd like to populate the name of a newly created store with the name of the company referenced in the `CompanyId` column.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why not let the name be nullable and use ISNULL or COALESCE when selecting the data? What you are trying to do there is pretty non-standard.

Comment: There should be no reason you would need to store the company name in both tables. The `Companies` table is your lookup. What happens if a `Stores` record changes `CompanyId`, you would also have to update the `Name` in `Stores`.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear with my column naming.  I'm not trying to duplicate data; the `Companies(Name)` column is ultimately intended to contain different data than the `Stores(Name)` column.  I definitely wouldn't allow either to be null in this case, and as a nice aid to the end user, it would be handy is the store name defaulted to the company name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend having the CRUD (CReate/Update/Delete) logic create the initial Stores row with the same name as the Companies row.  How you do this depends on your implementation, but here is one example:

```
declare @Name varchar(50), @CompanyId int
set @Name = 'XYZ Industries, Inc.'    
insert into Companies (Name) select @Name

select @CompanyId = scope_identity()

if @CompanyId is null -- no rows inserted
    return 

insert into Stores (CompanyId, Name)
select @CompanyId, @Name
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), the `default` keyword has a limited syntax:

> Specifies the value provided for the column when a value is not
>   explicitly supplied during an insert. DEFAULT definitions can be
>   applied to any columns except those defined as timestamp, or those
>   with the IDENTITY property. If a default value is specified for a
>   user-defined type column, the type should support an implicit
>   conversion from constant_expression to the user-defined type. DEFAULT
>   definitions are removed when the table is dropped. **Only a constant
>   value, such as a character string; a scalar function (either a system,
>   user-defined, or CLR function); or NULL can be used as a default.** To
>   maintain compatibility with earlier versions of SQL Server, a
>   constraint name can be assigned to a DEFAULT.

You can assign a scalar function to the default, but you cannot pass it any column values as variables, or you will get an error like this:

> The name "Fields" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: Don't use @@identity here. You should use SCOPE_IDENTITY. If there is an insert trigger on Companies that inserts an identity you will get that value instead of newly insert one.

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  I'm hoping to handle this within the table definition so that I don't have to worry about it later when inserting store rows (which would hypothetically be done by multiple different client applications).

Comment: @SeanLange Good catch, thank you.  Changed `@@identity` to `scope_identity()`.

Comment: @Scott Hypothetically each client application may each have its own business rules for the default store name.  Maybe the next one would want it to be "<Company Name> Store #1".  The next client application wants the default to be "Corporate HQ".  But if you really want to use the same default for potentially multiple applications, ideally you have some sort of library or entry point like a stored procedure that these applications can use to interact with your database.  This library would be an ideal place to set the default store name.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but consider the INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx